# Spark dump to parquet with column as array of structures

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I need to load a csv file which has a column that has an array of structures, and dump it to another location in parquet format.
My csv file has two columns, column A and B.
The data type of column B is `array<struct<x: bigint, y:bigint>>`

I tried to load the csv file with a schema as follows:

```
val schemaB = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField("x",LongType),StructField("y",LongType))))
val schema = new StructType().add("A",StringType).add("B",schemaB)
spark.read.option("sep", "\t").schema(schema).csv(<location>)
```

However, this didn't work. I got the below error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: CSV data source does not support array<struct<x:bigint,y:bigint>&gt; data type.;</struct<x:bigint,y:bigint>
```

I even tried casting to the required type, but that didn't work.

This is an example of how the column B looks:

```
|B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|68222:102332,21215:1000,10982:70330,|
|93302:13320,263721:902615,9382:100020,|
```

Comment: Can you share your sample input data? How could you have a array type in csv file ?

Comment: @koiralo I have added the sample. The csv would have it as a string. I need to be able to write it as an array of structs when dumping in parquet.

Comment: If so you can just read it as string, parse and convert to any type you want and write it as parquet.

Comment: Yes like I mentioned in the post, I tried to read it as a string and cast it to an array before writing to parquet. That didn't work as well. I got an error that cannot cast string to array of structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` function if you are using latest version of spark **i.e 2.4+**

Read as a string first, `split` by `","` to get list and again `split` by `":"` to get `x` and `y`

```
val schema = new StructType().add("A",StringType).add("B",StringType)
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").schema(schema).csv("path to csv")
val splitExpr =  expr("transform(split(B, ','), x -> (split(x, ':')[0] as x, split(x, ':')[1] as y))")

val result = df.select($"A", splitExpr.cast("array<struct<x: long, y:long>>") as "B" )
```

Now this you can save in parquet 
If You are using older version of spark then you need to write an udf 
Final Schema:

```
root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- x: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: long (nullable = true)
```